# Allure not able to read output.xml file generated by AllureReportLibrary in Robot Framework

Tags: python, xml, robotframework, allure, robotframework-ide

I am using Ride (RobotFramework IDE) and I have imported Library `AllureReportLibrary` in my project. 
Using the `Set Output Dir`, I am creating a Directory `C:/AutomationLogs/Allure` and all the allure properties and xml files are getting generated in that path.

```
Set Output Dir   C:/AutomationLogs/
```

Then I am using the "allure serve C:\AutomationLogs\Allure" command to try and generate the html report file in command prompt, but it shows the below error -

> "Could not read result
>   C:\AutomationLogs\Allure\f56f4796-d30a-47f3-a988-d17f6c4e13ca-testsuite.xml:
>   {} com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot
>   deserialize va lue of type
>   `ru.yandex.qatools.allure.model.SeverityLevel` from String "None":
>   value not one of declared Enum instance names: [trivial, blocker,
>   minor, normal, critical]"

The xml file "`f56f4796-d30a-47f3-a988-d17f6c4e13ca-testsuite.xml`" was generated using the AllureReportLibrary

Also the index.html file which is generated after the command opens after this command and shows Allure Report unknown 
unknown - unknown (Unknown)   0 test cases    NaN%

I am using the below -
Allure version - 2.4.1

Ride version - RIDE 1.5.2.1 running on Python 2.7.12.

I am new to Robot Framework and Allure. Please let me know whether I have implemented it correctly and why I am facing the above error.

-Ryan M

Comment: Have you tried with the Allure 1 command line: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure1/releases/tag/allure-core-1.5.2?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the `1.1.1` version of Allure Adaptor for Robot Framework and the severity is picked from the test case tags and added as a label under the `test-case` element of the report.

However, it seems that Allure `2.6.0` is also expecting a valid value for the `severity` attribute of the `test-case` element.

In order to use Allure2 with the current reports I have altered `AllureListener.py` to also add the severity to the test case:

```
elif tag in SEVERITIES:
    test.severity = tag
    test.labels.append(TestLabel(
        name='severity',
        value=tag
    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

***How to create the Allure reports in Robot Framework ?***

Initially, Download the Command line and UNzip the file and save the path of the bin folder in environment.

Link : http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/qameta/allure/allure-commandline/2.8.0/allure-commandline-2.8.0.zip

Unzip the above file then put it in the Environment folder.

Then Pip install the below modules

1. pip install allure-robotframework
2. pip install robotframework-allurereport

In robot file,  Add the Library in Settings like,
Example :

Library           AllureReportLibrary     D:\eclipse\RobotFramework\results

Then Use the Below commands to run the robot code.

robot --listener allure_robotframework;D:\eclipse\RobotFramework\results 
     Example.txt

Finally,

Generate the HTML file by,

allure generate  D:\eclipse\RobotFramework\results

Note : Use the same path what you used in the previous command to generate the HTml.file.
and
Open in Mozhila FireFox.   It wont be work in Chrome. I dont know exactly why.

Regards,

Vijay

Answer (score 0):

If your output.xml has `severity = None` for any testcase then the allure-robotframework-adaptor will give the error that you have mentioned. Creating `TestCase()` object with `severity=''` in `start_suitesetup` method of `AllureListener.py` will do the trick.

```
def start_suitesetup(self, name, attributes):
    ....
    ....
    test = TestCase(name=name,
                    description=description,
                    start=now(),
                    attachments=[],
                    labels=[],
                    parameters=[],
                    steps=[],
                    severity='')
```